# Print 2D Array using JOptionPane dialog box

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, joptionpane

I already made the code and i can input values using the JOptionPane Input Dialog.

But the problem is when printing the ouptut of the 2d array it shows like this:

[image]

The output should be like this: (can be without the equal and underline)

```
5       9       8     =  22
3       8       2     =  13
4       3       9     =  16
__________________________
12      20      19
```

This is the code. I can input values but the only problem is how can i print the matrix.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TwoDimensional_Array {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String output = "";

    int [][] num = new int [3][3];
    int [] sum = new int[10];
    int [] sum1 = new int [10];
    
    System.out.println("\n3 by 3 Array - Enter Matrix Elements.");

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter elements in pockets ["+ i +"]["+ j +"]:", "3 by 3 - Two-Dimensonal Array", -1);
            num[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {    
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            sum[i] = sum[i] + num[i][j];
            sum1[i] = sum1[i] + num[j][i];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            output += (num[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        output += ("=\t" + sum[i]); //print the sum of rows
    }
    output += ("__________________________________");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        output += (sum1[i] + "\t"); // print the sum of columns
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "Two-Dimensional Array", -1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a new line in the dialog, append the `\n` character instead of the `\t` character.

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-newline) ist some more information about the Java line separators.